# Why is the invalid procedure or call error occurring on the change pivot table range line?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Is the issue with the changepivottablecache line?

I have tried to this workbook, but I am able to execute the line to refresh the table.

I have looked at several fixes online but none work as expected.

```
Dim Data_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Pivot_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim StartPoint As Range
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim PivotName As String
Dim NewRange As String
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

'Set Pivot Table & Source Worksheet
Set Data_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Set Pivot_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetTable")

'Enter in Pivot Table Name
PivotName = "PivotTable2"
'Defining Staring Point & Dynamic Range
Data_Sheet.Activate
Set StartPoint = Data_Sheet.Range("A1")
LastCol = StartPoint.End(xlToRight).Column
DownCell = StartPoint.End(xlDown).Row
Set DataRange = Data_Sheet.Range(StartPoint, Cells(DownCell, LastCol))
NewRange = Data_Sheet.Name & "!" & DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Change Pivot Table Data Source Range Address
Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables(PivotName). _
ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=NewRange)

'Ensure Pivot Table is Refreshed
Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables(PivotName).RefreshTable

'Complete Message
Pivot_Sheet.Activate
MsgBox "Your Pivot Table is now updated."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully change an exisiting pivot table using the following code. You may need to adapt to your situation. Original code from [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8f96cf6b-86d6-4f8d-9a06-3932a0942d44/change-data-source-using-vba?forum=exceldev)

```
Sub ChangePTCache()
Dim PTRange As Range
Dim con_end As String
con_end = Range("'Sheet1'!A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1).Address
Set PTRange = Range("'Sheet1'!A1:" & con_end)
Sheets(1).PivotTables(1).ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches. _
    Create(xlDatabase, PTRange)
End Sub
```